# Regex to match string with one number and one capital

Tags: javascript

I need to match a string that has at least one number and one capital letter. I have this:

```
/[a-z][A-Z][0-9]+/
```

but this only matches a string with lowercase letters first, followed by uppercase letter and then a digit. I need to be able to match them in any order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use a pair of look-ahead assertions:

```
(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d).+
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/nn5PyKAcd1TT4PEm)

*Edited to capture the string, not merely match it.*

Note: you only need the final `.+` if you want to capture the result. If you simply want to do a test for whether the string contains at least one number and one capital letter, you don't need that final `.+`. For example, this

```
'aB9'.match(/(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)/)
```

returns `[""]`, which evaluates as `true` if you put it in an `if` or `while`. On the other hand, this

```
'aB9'.match(/(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d).+/)
```

returns `["aB9"]`. Use whichever flavor best suits your needs.

Comment: I like it and use it frequently. Wish I could claim credit for it. :)

Comment: You'll need to anchor it. Your demo isn't matching anything

Comment: @AmitJoki It works just fine in the sense that it matches the string; it just doesn't capture anything. That said, I edited my answer to capture the string, not merely match it. If yours was the downvote, I would appreciate if you removed it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to anchor the lookaround if you want to capture it, otherwise it wont work.

But if you want to just test the string, Ed's solution works.

```
(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d).*
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/xIDpaYInYPvkZqRf)

Comment: This answer needs clarification, as the regex works fine even without the final `.*`. For example, `'aB9'.match(/(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)/)` returns a match; it just happens to be an empty string. It even works in your Debuggex demo without the final `.*`. That portion of the regex is only necessary to capture the string; it's not necessary if simply testing for a match.

Comment: @EdCottrell OP wants to match it

Comment: he says `but this only matches a string with lowercase letters first, followed by uppercase letter and then a digit. I need to be able to match them in any order.`

Comment: Nonetheless, it needs clarification. You wrote, "You need to anchor the lookaround, otherwise it wont work." That is true if you are looking to *capture* the text. It's incorrect if you merely want to *match* it, which is what OP asked about.

Comment: Looks good. By the way, if you were the downvote on my answer, I'd appreciate if you removed it, as I have also clarified my answer. :)

Comment: I did - with the explanation, your answer is a great one.

Answer (score 0):

### [Regex Example](http://regex101.com/r/aU7aV9)

```
^.*(?=.*[A-Z]).*(?=.*\d).*$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/4uwkgmH59nmKyu5J)

**Description:**

This will match any `searchtext` with at least 1 capital letter and 1 digit.

---

### [Regex Example With forcing a minimum number of characters](http://regex101.com/r/yU3oY9)

```
\A(?=\S*?[A-Z])(?=\S*?[0-9])\S{6,}\z
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/B9tw2BizilQNlpTn)

**Regex Explained:**

```
\A(?=\S*?[A-Z])(?=\S*?[0-9])\S{6,}\z
    \A assert position at start of the string
    (?=\S*?[A-Z]) Positive Lookahead - Assert that the regex below can be matched
        \S*? match any non-white space character [^\r\n\t\f ]
            Quantifier: Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed [lazy]
        [A-Z] match a single character present in the list below
            A-Z a single character in the range between A and Z (case sensitive)
    (?=\S*?[0-9]) Positive Lookahead - Assert that the regex below can be matched
        \S*? match any non-white space character [^\r\n\t\f ]
            Quantifier: Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed [lazy]
        [0-9] match a single character present in the list below
            0-9 a single character in the range between 0 and 9
    \S{6,} match any non-white space character [^\r\n\t\f ]
        Quantifier: Between 6 and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
    \z assert position at the very end of the string
```

**Description:**

The above regex requires 1 capital letter, 1 number, and at least 6 characters long

Comment: Why the `\S*?` and `\S{6,}`? OP never said anything about those requirements.

Comment: just incase he missed that...i'll add that as additional regex